# What should I return from a function?

Tags: design, c, functions

I have a function in C language which takes 3 matrices as arguments; It performs matrix multiplication of first 2 matrices and stores the result in the 3rd one.

My question is what should I return from the function. Should I return the resultant matrix it self (rather the pointer to it) so that function calls can be chained togather like so :

```
display_matrix(multiply_matrix(A, B, C));
```

Or should I return 0 or 1 based on whether the operation was successful or not (incorrect dimensions might return failure)? In this case the line shown above would look something like this.

```
multiply_matrix(A, B, C);
display_matrix(C);
```

So, what would be the better way to do it? Or is it just a matter of choice?

Comment: It'a matter of opinion but I like the idea of returning status of the operation.

Comment: Under what circumstances would matrix multiplication fail?

Comment: Mismatched dimensions as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 9):

Since your operation can fail, you need *some* way to represent this.
The chaining design is nice-to-have, but is possible only if you don't need to return anything else instead.

The options are:

- return success or failure codes

  - con: in this case you obviously can't use the function chaining style
  - con: you also need to pepper your code with tests and error handling
  - con: any operations whose result *isn't* checked may leave the out-param in an unexpected state
  - pro: if some operations does fail, you know exactly where it happened (assuming you don't copy-paste your error handling boilerplate incorrectly...)

  Your sample code should actually look something like:

  ```
  if ((rc=multiply_matrix(A, B, C)) != MAT_OK) {
    display_matrix_error(rc, A, B);
  } else {
    display_matrix(C);
  }
  ```
- use some matrix equivalent of `NaN` to represent failed computations, and just pass them through your function chain silently.

  - pro: in this case you get the nice function chaining style
  - pro: you don't need explicit error-checking everywhere
  - con: you can't tell which step failed if a long chain of computations results in an invalid matrix

  Your sample code really will look like you posted:

  ```
  display_matrix(multiply_matrix(A, B, C));
  ```

  where the display function needs to know how to handle an invalid input.

Answer (score 7):

Number of issues here. Let me tease them apart.

First, don't give back your result with both an out parameter and a return. That's just confusing.  Pick one.

Second, [c has no exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891766/how-to-throw-an-exception-in-c). Instead c functions either return errors or they handle/avoid them so that no error escapes. If you choose to return your result then you need a robust way of always returning something meaningful.

Third, if you return your error status and return the result in an out parameter please document this clearly.

Answer (score 0):

In C it's not uncommon to return pointers. Returning a null pointer could signify failure. Plus returning a pointer avoids a potentially large amount of data copying.

So you can have both error returns and (maybe somewhat limited, depending on other choices you make) function chaining. (Note your matrix functions would need to accept input parameters as pointers as well).

Function chaining would have to deal with getting a null pointer on input. But this could be treated analogously to NAN values for floating point arithmetic. If a null ptr is passed to `display_matrix()` then a "Not a Matrix" message would be displayed. If `multiply_matrix()` received a null, if would return a null.

Finally if you need more diagnostic info than just "it failed", you could use an approach like C's `errno` which gives a failure reason.

Comment: Oh god no! Don't imitate the horribly broken `errno` pattern.

Comment: @user1118321 I'm aware of difficulties with `errno` in a multithreaded environment, and with ambiguities WRT when `errno` changes, but are you referring to other "brokenness"?

Comment: The entire concept of an error stored at a static location that you have to know to check (and sometimes set, apparently) is extremely problematic. It's not just ambiguities of *when* to check it, but about not having any way to know that it even exists. When a function returns a value, it's easy to see that you have to check it just from looking at the function prototype. But when it sets a hidden variable at a magical location, you don't even know *to* check it, let alone when, you're pretty much guaranteeing failure for the user of that function.

Comment: I disagree on some points. `errno` doesn't have to be a static location, it can be macro that evaluates to any number of things, including a thread local variable. I don't consider it magical, because all the C libraries I've seen that use it, document it's use. When a function returns a value, you can't unambiguously tell from prototype that it can signify an error. You must look at documentation. There is a great body of evidence that suggests success with its use. Also, it's a common pattern in hardware architecture: Machine Check Architecture for x64, AER for PCIe, APEI for ACPI, etc

Comment: @Χpẘ when a function returns a value of type `struct { ErrorType error; TypeYouWant value; }`, it's unambiguously an error signal. Some other symbol `errno` is *magical* because it does not form part of the function signature. It is popular in hardware because it lacks the abstractive power to have a *better* error handling channel

Comment: @Caleth I've never seen that definition of "magical". Maybe there's a better term, such as "not part of function signature". The "errno" pattern allows the OP to chain operations and be able to get diagnostic info, which he apparently wants to do.  So it's a tradeoff between convenience in programming and clarity of interface. OP doesn't say how broad consumers of APIs are - my guess is small # of consumers. In which case the errno pattern's benefit probably outweigh disadvantages. Of course you could combine chaining with error info, by accepting your struct as inputs, but that's overkill IMO